# How to start Cloud SQL proxy with supervisor

Tags: google-cloud-sql, supervisord, cloud-sql-proxy

I tried to start a CloudSQL proxy on `supervisor`, however I have no idea what is wrong with it. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) does not show any clues to this issue. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

I tried the setup on a clean Ubuntu 16 and then installed supervisor and downloaded cloud_sql_proxy.  And I put files under `/root` and execute as root for debugging.

Here is my current setup:

**/etc/supervisord.conf**

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; the path to the socket file
chmod=0766                  ; socket file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; main log file; default $CWD/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; max main logfile bytes b4 rotation; default 50MB
logfile_backups=10           ; # of main logfile backups; 0 means none, default 10
loglevel=info                ; log level; default info; others: debug,warn,trace
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; supervisord pidfile; default supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false               ; start in foreground if true; default false
minfds=1024                  ; min. avail startup file descriptors; default 1024
minprocs=200                 ; min. avail process descriptors;default 200

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/cloud_sql_proxy.conf**

```
[program:cloud_sql_proxy]
command=/root/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances="project_id:us-central1:instance-name" -credential_file="/root/service-account.json"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=1
startsecs=8
stdout_logfile=/var/log/cloud_sql_proxy-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/cloud_sql_proxy-stderr.log
```

I got the following error after inspecting `/tmp/supervisord.log`:

```
2018-10-14 15:49:49,984 INFO spawned: 'cloud_sql_proxy' with pid 3569
2018-10-14 15:49:49,989 INFO exited: cloud_sql_proxy (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-10-14 15:49:50,991 INFO spawned: 'cloud_sql_proxy' with pid 3574
2018-10-14 15:49:50,996 INFO exited: cloud_sql_proxy (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-10-14 15:49:51,998 INFO gave up: cloud_sql_proxy entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2018-10-14 15:51:46,981 INFO spawned: 'cloud_sql_proxy' with pid 3591
2018-10-14 15:51:46,986 INFO exited: cloud_sql_proxy (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-10-14 15:51:47,989 INFO spawned: 'cloud_sql_proxy' with pid 3596
2018-10-14 15:51:47,998 INFO exited: cloud_sql_proxy (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-10-14 15:51:47,999 INFO gave up: cloud_sql_proxy entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to figure out a working solution, and here is it:

Create a new file /root/start_cloud_sql_proxy.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/root/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances="project_id:us-central1:instance-name" -credential_file="/root/service-account.json"
```

Under /etc/supervisor/conf.d/cloud_sql_proxy.conf, change the command to execute a bash file:

```
command=/root/start_cloud_sql_proxy.sh
```